# Calculate constant E value

Tags: objective-c, math

I am doing a calculation in Objective-C. I have one value `4.0468564224e-33`. I dont know what that `e` constant's value is. Please help me: how can I calculate this constant value? How are constant values declared and calculated in Objective-C?

Answer (score 5):

The e is part of [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

> Most calculators and many computer programs present very large and very small results in scientific notation. Because superscripted exponents like 10<sup>7</sup> cannot always be conveniently represented on computers, typewriters and calculators, an alternative format is often used: the letter *E* or *e* represents *times ten raised to the power of*, thus replacing the *× 10*, followed by the value of the exponent. Note that the character *e* is not related to the [mathematical constant *e*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) (a confusion that is less likely with capital *E*); and though it stands for exponent, the notation is usually referred to as *(scientific) E notation* or *(scientific) e notation*, rather than *(scientific) exponential notation* (though the latter also occurs).

`4.0468564224e-33` means 4.0468564224 * 10<sup>-33</sup>, or `0.0000000000000000000000000000000040468564224`.

Comment: i am used this constant value in my calumniation .i was succeed.thank u very much.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this citation for future users which is reverse of the asked above question. Google brought me here, So I think this is the best place to add this answer.

```
NSString *num = @"5.0E0";
```

To get the processed value from above string you need to simply do this:

```
CGFloat secNum = [num floatValue]; // this will feed 5 to secNum
```

Hope it could help someone.

Answer (score -3):

If you just need to use *e*'s value you can get it from math.h

```
#import <math.h>
...

NSLog(@"e: %g", M_E);
```

Comment: Your answer in and of itself is correct, but not correct in the context of the question, which is referring to scientific notation.