# how to calculate mathematical double values

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to calculate `4.0468564224e-33` value.  But unfortunately I am getting a result of `0.0000000`.  I think the problem is at the `e` value.

How can I calculate these mathematical calculation?  Is there any necessity of importing mathematical classes?

Comment: err what language...does it support doubles?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717669/calculate-constant-e-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`4.0468564224e-33` is  `4.0468564224 * 10⁻³³`, that is `0.0000000000000000000000000000000040468564224` - very close to zero.

If your output function is rounding to 7 decimal digits, you would get `0.0000000` as output even though the input is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Anders Lindahl explained [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726684/how-to-calculate-mathematical-double-values/5726791#5726791) you see zero, but didn't suggest any solution.

One solution is to request the output of more decimals by using `%.43f` instead of `%f` (`%.7f`).

Another solution is to request exponentiation notation by using `%e` (`%.10e`) instead of `%f`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using something like

```
NSLog("%d", yourValue);
```

while you should use:

```
NSLog("%f", yourValue);
```

since your value is a float and not an integer.

```
%d => int
%f => float
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSNumber` for your large `double` calculation.
Read Apple Doc for [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

See SO post for NSNumber

[NSNumber Calculations & precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333755/nsnumber-calculations-precision)